# How to test that ActiveJob is enqueued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob

I have a create action that calls an ActiveJob if the record is successfully saved.

```
def create
  @object = Object.new(importer_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @object.save
      MyJob.perform_later( @object.id )
      format.html { redirect_to @object, notice: t('.notice') }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test that the Job is correctly called in a controller spec.

```
describe "POST #create" do
  it {
    expect {
      post :create, { object: valid_attributes }
    }.to change(Object, :count).by(1)
  }
  it { 
    expect {
      post :create, { object: valid_attributes }
    }.to have_enqueued_job(MyJob) 
  }  
end
```

But I get

```
Failure/Error:
  expect {
    post :create, { object: valid_attributes }
  }.to have_enqueued_job(MyJob)
  expected to enqueue exactly 1 jobs, but enqueued 0
```

The first test is passing, so I know the Object is saved successfully. What is the correct way to test that an ActiveJob is enqueued?

Answer (score 13):

If you need to check that your job has been enqueued several times, you can now do [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers%3Ahave_enqueued_job):

```
expect {
  3.times { HelloJob.perform_later }
}.to have_enqueued_job(HelloJob).at_least(2).times
```

Comment: not exactly what he asked, but exactly what I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I've always looked at the size of `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs` to test if a job was called. giving the code

```
it 'does something' do
  expect {
    post :create, { object: valid_attributes }
  }.to change {
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.count
  }.by 1
end
```

You should make sure that you are setting the enqueued_jobs to an empty array after each spec to avoid any unexpected behaviour. You can do this in the `spec/rails_helper.rb`

Comment: thanks @petecss, is there any way to check that the correct job and queue are called. Or even that the correct params are passed to the job?

Comment: `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs` is an array. so you can inspect it. Calling something like `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.first` will give you the first job. This is simply a hash that you can inspect `[:args]` for instance gives you an array of arguments such as the name of the method called. You should put a debugger in your spec and inspect `enqueued_jobs` when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

In official docs here is have_enqueued_job matcher

The have_enqueued_job (also aliased as enqueue_job) matcher is used to check if given ActiveJob job was enqueued.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher

Answer (score 0):

we can use perform_enqueued_jobs method to wait for the jobs to finish